# How to save the result of a SQL query into a variable in VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to execute a select statement and put the result of it (which is only 1 record with 1 value) in a variable.

**This is in VBA code in access.**

```
Private Sub Child_Click()
   Dim Childnummer As Integer
   Dim childnaam As String
   Childnummer = Me.Keuzelijst21.Value
   DoCmd.Close
   DoCmd.OpenForm "submenurubrieken", acNormal, , " rubrieknummer = " & Childnummer & ""
   childnaam = rubrieknaamSQL(Childnummer)
   Forms!submenurubrieken.Tv_rubrieknaam.Value = childnaam
End Sub

Public Function rubrieknaamSQL(Child As Integer)
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "SELECT rubrieknaam FROM dbo_tbl_rubriek where rubrieknummer = " & Child & ""
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
End Function
```

Comment: Why can't you just store the value of the record with myVar = rst!nameOfValueField ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply have your Function return the value from the Recordset:

```vbs
Public Function rubrieknaamSQL(Child As Integer)
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "SELECT rubrieknaam FROM dbo_tbl_rubriek where rubrieknummer = " & Child & ""
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
   ' new code:
   rubrieknaamSQL = rst!rubrieknaam
   rst.Close
   Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: was my first time making such a query in vba. thanks anyways!

Comment: what does the ! in rst!rubrieknaam do?

Comment: @Jorge - See the related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2923957/2144390).

Comment: This only returns the first matching result. How would you return ALL results that match the query?

Comment: @PatrickConwell - You process each row by looping through the recordset with `Do Until rst.EOF` and `rst.MoveNext`

Comment: Ah! Okay, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pretty much one line by using the "DLookup" Function

```
rubrieknaam = Nz(DLookup("rubrieknaam ", "dbo_tbl_rubriek ", rubrieknummer & " =[Child]"), 0)
```

where Child is the ID of the record you are looking for.