# Msgbox From query access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access form that contains an Id field.Once a user enters the Id , i want to run a query on the after update event to get the patients history field and display it as a msg box.

The query is as follows :

```
"Select Patients.[Patient History] From Patients Where Patients.ID = " & Me.PatientID
```

How can i do this?

thank you

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992226/how-to-save-the-result-of-a-sql-query-into-a-variable-in-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *DLookup* in a one-liner:

```
MsgBox Nz(DLookup("[Patient History]", "Patients", "ID = " & Me!PatientID.Value & "")), vbInformation + vbOkOnly, "Patient History"
```