# Using Access VBA, how to count number of output records in a select query and store the count as a VBA variable?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2013, and in particular I'm stuck using the VBA code editor due to boss' instruction to minimise saved queries and tables - and also I don't have the access to modify table structure.

I have two tables: InvoiceDetails and AllItems, joined by ItemID.

```
INVOICEDETAILS     ALLITEMS
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯     ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
ItemID←-----------→ItemID
InvoiceNumber      Invoiced (Yes/No)
```

Sometimes an `Item` in InvoiceDetails can be individually credited, in which case the corresponding `Invoiced` in AllItems will be unchecked. I am trying to compare the

- TotalItemCount = number of `Items` with a given `InvoiceNumber` "1"

with

- InvoicedItemCount = number of `Items` with the given `InvoiceNumber` "1" that are still `Invoiced`

For the first number, I have

```
TotalItemCount = DCount("ItemID", "InvoiceDetails", "InvoiceNumber = 1")
```

For the second number, I have a SELECT query that gives me the count in SQL but I don't know how to convert that into the VBA variable `InvoicedItemCount`.

```
SELECT Count(InvoiceDetails.ItemID) 
FROM InvoiceDetails INNER JOIN AllItems 
     ON InvoiceDetails.LoadID = AllItems.LoadID 
WHERE InvoicedDetails.InvoiceNumber = 1 AND AllItems.Invoiced = True);
```

I know of `DoCmd.RunSQL` but AFAIK that just runs the query and doesn't give an output-able integer to be stored as a VBA variable. Is there a way to do this solely in VBA?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23992226/42346

Comment: Thank you Bernie! The solution there worked for me.

Comment: Cheers, mate! Happy coding to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obtained the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992226/how-to-save-the-result-of-a-sql-query-into-a-variable-in-vba), to which I was directed by Bernie.

Assuming that the SQL query returns one record, with only one field, and we want that single value:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT x FROM y WHERE z=z;"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

VariableName = rst.Fields(0)

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```