# How do I save the results of a results of a sql query in a vba variable?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have data with a date that I want to exclude from my current data. I am trying to pull the required date from a sql table and compare it to the dates in the excel sheet.

The sql code is

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection    
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset    
DIM code_string as STRING  
code_string = "select date from table WHERE foo foo foo"
```

and the result is a date that I want to save in a variable.

I have tried  `Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)` that I found here: [How to save the result of a SQL query into a variable in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992226/how-to-save-the-result-of-a-sql-query-into-a-variable-in-vba)
and vba gives me an object required error.

Is there a way to save the results of a sql query in a vba variable?

Comment: You need to first open a recordset - would help to show the rest of your code: we can't tell much from one line.

Comment: Have you added the ADODB library via Tools>>References?

Comment: Here is what worked, thank you @TimWilliams
`Set rs = con.Execute(code_string)                
        Sheets("test").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` and I will compare everything to the value in A2